# Running external JS within a PHP webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a `PHP` version of my webpage, and it finds my external css just fine.  However, I cannot get it to load the external `JS` code and I can't figure out why that is.  I am using WinSCP to connect to a server.

I know that PHP is server-side, and technically, the JS is also on the server right?  In my code, I link the css down to the root folder, and it comes back in the PHP version of the webpage.  But JS won't.  I have searched for quite some time on how to make this work, and perhaps it doesn't.

```
<?php
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 $header= $path."/includes/header.php";
 include ($header);
 $menu= $path."/includes/menu.php";
 include ($menu);
 $footer= $path."/includes/footer.php";
 include ($footer);

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Profile</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="../css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="../js/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
```

Comment: Use browser inspector for network and see that `.js` file status is 404 or something else?

Comment: No, it just doesn't load any of the script.

Comment: It is not possible that it doesn't load any. It must be 2xx for success, 3xx, 4xx for some kind of errors. `<script>` tag is correct so, there should be a file status on network tab for browser dev tools.
In case that there is no `.js` file loaded the `.css` should not loaded too. If that case make sure that PHP contains no error or it will be white page and nothing will be loaded.

Comment: And as you say it is not possible, yet the scripts do not load. I verified this with a color box on the top right which is supposed to change colors of the footer and header.  It did not work.

Answer (score -1):

It should be working. Load the php script in a browser. Right click, `Inspect`and go to `Console`. (But I guess you should know how to go to the console already.)

If it mention anything about a `404`, the file doesn't exist or you're not putting the correct url in the `src=""`.

If it's not, please comment the error in the console. If there isn't any, the script was loaded, but you don't realize it somehow.

**Edit:** Also, maybe your mime type is wrong, if the above doesn't work, try replacing `type="text/javascript"` to `type="application/javascript"`.